# leetcode problem 1395 - Count Number of Teams

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

class Solution:

```
 def numTeams(self, rating: List[int]) -> int:
        length = len(rating)
        count = 0
        for i in range(length):
            for j in range(i+1,length):
                for k in range(j+1,length):
                    if rating[i] < rating[j] < rating[k]:
                        count += 1
                    elif rating[i] > rating[j] > rating[k]:
                        count += 1
        return count
```

this is giving TLE on a very big size of array. how can I optimize it, I went through the discuss forum also but everybody used sum() which I am not aware of. can using recursion help optimizing it.

Comment: Use the builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function.

Comment: And [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is very useful too.

Comment: Also, you are brute-forcing the total count, checking every combination, which takes a long time because your algorithm is of factorial *runtime complexity*. A more clever solution is to do two passes : one left-to-right, one right-to-left, each time keeping a record of what was seen before to compute efficiently, in linear time, the solution.

Comment: There also is a [Dicuss page](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-number-of-teams/discuss/) directly on the site.